# How to solve the slowdown caused by BackgroundWorker to update the Form?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, forms, backgroundworker

I'm using VB.Net. I would like that all my forms could check if exists connection to the server and when there isn't indicate it doing visible a PictureBox. The code works fine when there is connection, but freeze the form when not each five seconds approximadely. In first place I imagine that this was happening because I call Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000), but when there is connection this line is executed too, so I don't understand why this happen only when there isn't connection. Could be happened because to change Visible property? I have try enure it this property changing only when it's neccesary.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles Me.Load
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker.DoWork
    While True
        Me.IndicateIfExistsConnection()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub IndicateIfExistsConnection()
    If Me.offlinePictureBox.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.offlinePictureBox.BeginInvoke(Sub() IndicateIfExistsConnectionMustBeOnUIThread())
    Else
        IndicateIfExistsConnectionMustBeOnUIThread()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub IndicateIfExistsConnectionMustBeOnUIThread()
    If Not DAOUtils.ExistsServerConnection() Then MakeVisibleOfflineWarning() Else MakeInvisibleOfflineWarning()
End Sub

Private Sub MakeVisibleOfflineWarning()
    If Not offlinePictureBox.Visible Then offlinePictureBox.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub MakeInvisibleOfflineWarning()
    If offlinePictureBox.Visible Then offlinePictureBox.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    backgroundWorker.CancelAsync()
End Sub
```

Edit:

I have tried the solution of @Jimi and @dbasnett. Both works fine. Finally I used the @Jimi's solution although I don't know if I have understood it well. The code is now like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles Me.Load
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker.DoWork
    While True
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, DAOUtils.ExistsServerConnection())
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged
    Dim existsServerConnection As Boolean = e.UserState

    If existsServerConnection Then offlinePictureBox.Visible = False Else offlinePictureBox.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is overly separated, but it looks fine. You need to provide a [mcve] that we can use to replicate your issue to solve the problem. Can you provide one?

Comment: I think `DAOUtils.ExistsServerConnection()` is what you need to call in the worker's thread. Your code right now call it in the main thread.

Comment: A number of problems:  1. `DAOUtils.ExistsServerConnection()` needs to be called from the BGW Thread, not the UI Thread. 2. Remove `Me` from `Me.IndicateIfExistsConnection()` 3. Use the BGW's [ReportProgress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress) method: the related event is raised in the UI Thread ; **do not** `Invoke()` or `BeginInvoke()` from a BGW Thread 4. When you `BeginInvoke()` (not here, in general), you don't need to check `InvokeRequired` and your target marshaller is a Form, not a child Control (a PictureBox, here).

Comment: So: 1. Set [WorkerReportsProgress = True](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress) beforehand 2. Subscribe to the [ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged) event. 3. Raise the event calling `ReportProgress()`, passing a value, when needed, in the `UserState` argument. 4. In the `ProgressChanged` handler, only change the `offlinePictureBox` visibility status. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question.  BUT based on my understanding this might do the trick.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t As Task = Task.Run(Sub() ConnectedAnimation())
End Sub

Private Sub ConnectedAnimation()
    Do
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        If isConnected() Then
            Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() offlinePictureBox.Visible = False)
        Else
            Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() offlinePictureBox.Visible = True)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Private Function isConnected() As Boolean
    Dim rv As Boolean = False
    ' <<<<<     code to check connection here     >>>>>
    '  rv = DAOUtils.ExistsServerConnection()
    Return rv
End Function
```